# Vectors in trapezium

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> A trapezoid $ABCD $ is given. $AB $ is parallel to $DC$. Let the point $E$ be the bisector of $AB$ and point $S$ the bisector of the $CD$. Let the points $F$ and $G$ be such points that $\vec{BC} = \vec {EF}$ and $\vec{AD} = \vec {EG}$. Prove that the points $F$, $G$ and $S$ lie on the same line (they are collinear).

First, I decided $\vec{FG}= \vec{FS}k$  ($k$ is something) but then I freeze, how do I solve this?

Comment: Which sides of the trapezoid are parallel? Shouldn't the points $F$ and $G$ lie on particular lines?

Comment: AB is parallel CD.

Comment: $F$ lies on $AD$ and $G$ lies on $BC$ right?

Comment: No. F, S and G all lie on the same line as D and C

Comment: This is not correct, I can give a counterexample then. There must be some other condition on $F$ and $G$

Comment: Why is it necessary that they have to be collinear? I can have $F$ and $G$ on $BC$ and $AD$ meeting the same condition of length.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer this question, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me a picture of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's put A at the origin.
Then let's define some vectors.

$\mathbf u$ points to $B$
$\mathbf v$ points to $D$
$\mathbf w$ points from B to $C.$
Note that $\mathbf w$ does not point directly to C.  $\mathbf u+\mathbf w$ does.

Where are E, S, F, G?

$E = \frac 12 \mathbf u$
$S= \frac 12 (\mathbf u + \mathbf w)+\frac 12\mathbf v$

$F = \frac 12 \mathbf u + \mathbf w\\
G = \frac 12 \mathbf u + \mathbf v$

$F, G, S$ lie on the same line if

$F-S$ is parallel to (a scalar multiple of) $G-S$

$F-S = \frac 12 \mathbf u + \mathbf w - \frac 12(\mathbf u + \mathbf v +\mathbf w) = \frac 12 \mathbf w - \frac 12 \mathbf v$
$G-S = \frac 12 \mathbf u + \mathbf v - \frac 12(\mathbf u + \mathbf v +\mathbf w) = \frac 12 \mathbf v - \frac 12 \mathbf w = -(F-S)$